# C# how to create add objects of abstract class to an Array?

Tags: c#, interface, abstract-class

1 At the end of this code, I am taking in all input values and adding them to a  to add to a Car object.

However there is an error when i try implement an abstract class, does anyone know a work around to this problem ? i.e. How to add an object of abstract class to a List/Array. Many thanks in advance

```
     string[] values = input.Split(',');
     string make = values[0];
     string model = values[1];
             
              if (double.TryParse(values[2], out double fuelAmount) == false)
              Console.WriteLine("Failed to parse the fuelAmount from the file");
              
              if (double.TryParse(values[3], out double mileage) == false)
              Console.WriteLine("Failed to parse the mileage from the file");

                // create a new car
              myCarList.Add(new Car(make, model, fuelAmount, mileage));
```

Comment: You can't create instances of abstract classes. Do you mean add instances of objects that inherit an abstract class? And what does the code in the question have to do with the question itself?

Comment: which class is abstract? what is the error message?

Answer (score 1):

you can create a class that implements your abstract class then use that class to add to your List<> or array, because you cannot create an instance of your abstract class.

```
public abstract class your_class_name_1
{
 //do your stuff here
}

 //inherit your abstract class so you can access the members of your abstract class 
public class your_class_name_2 : your_class_name_1
{
 //do your stuff here 
}

//and in your main method
static void Main(string[] args)
{
 your_class_name_2 myclass = new your_class_name_2();
  //then do your code here
}
```

i dont know which class is which but anyways hopes this will help you

Comment: Did you test this code?

Comment: @Enigmativity yes

Comment: It doesn't appear that you tested it very well.

Comment: @Enigmativity i just did now lol, thank you

Comment: Keep going. Two more errors.

Comment: @Enigmativity i hope i catch all lol

Answer (score 0):

The error is not about adding an object to a list. It is about creating an object of an abstract class. That is against the definition of an abstract class. In OOP you are not allowed to instantiate an abstract class.

Comment: How do you know that the OP is trying to "instantiate an abstract class"? He doesn't say that in his question.

Comment: He explained it: "How to add an object of abstract class to a List/Array". From his question, I found that he is creating an object from an abstract class, then wanted to add it to a list.

Comment: That's an assumption - the full context of that statement suggest he's having trouble implementing an abstract class. His "i.e." then says something different to the preceding part of the sentence, but it could be interpreted as he has an object with a "reference" to an abstract class. It's all to vague and unclear at this point.

Comment: I disagree with you. After more than 15 years of teaching developers, I am very familiar with the typical issues that new developers are facing. Our mind is full of assumptions and they are not necessarily wrong.

Comment: I agree that our assumptions are not necessarily wrong. You may indeed be right. But this site is attempting to be a reference site - kind of like wikipedia or a dictionary. You want to be able to rely on the answer 100%. You should seek clarification for your answers whenever there is any degree of ambiguity and only then post the answer.

Comment: You are right. Fair enough.